# Redirect to another page with $location.url wont work

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I'm new to AngularJS and i want to redirect my Application from Login.html to Homepage.html. I've read a lot and i found two ways for do that:

the first one consists in using `$window.location.href`and it works perfectly

the second one consist in using `$location.url` or `$location.path`and it doesn't work, it ad just /homepage.html to my actual URL.

How can i solve this? 
Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="loginController">
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username"><br>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"><br>
        <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        <p>{{result}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

        mainApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
            $scope.result = null;
            $scope.login = function(){
                $scope.result = "Logged in";
                $location.path('#/localhost/homepage.html').replace();
                $scope.apply();
            }
        }])
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks you all anticipatedly!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's important or not, but try changing `$scope.apply()` to `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: Doesn't work, the same, the URL changes but the page remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Υου should have:

```
$location.path('/homepage');
```

Or:

```
$location.path('/app/homepage');
```

Comment: It's the same, the URL changes but the page remains the same. Maybe it's a problem of directory? But, in case i put a worng error shouldn't come out an error message with "page not found" or something else?

Comment: In app.js have you declare the homepage and login properly?

Comment: If you have correct declaration try this:              $timeout(function(){ 
    //add the above code
 },1);

Comment: HTML and JS are both in the same page, and the two pages (Homapege and Login) are in the same directory htdocs/prova/asd.
Where i should put $timeout function?

Comment: There that you have now the $location.path.

Comment: Like this? 
$scope.timeout = function(){
    $scope.result = "Logged in";
    $location.path('/homepage').replace();
    $scope.$apply();
   }
really i don't know, i'm in tilt.

Comment: $scope.login = function(){ $scope.result = "Logged in";   $timeout(function(){$location.path(try the two that i send you)},1); $scope.apply(); }             //without replace

Comment: Doesn't work i got always http://localhost/prova/asd/login.html#/homepage this URL http://localhost/prova/asd/login.html#/homepage

Comment: Ok.So there is an issue on directories.My example of app run in localhost/#/app/login.With $location.path('/app/homepage') works fine.Hope this may help you to figure out what is wrong with yours path.

Comment: So i should create a direcotry in htdocs named app and there put login.html and homepage.html?

Comment: No i think this is not a good idea.With this , simply you will have another /app in the entire path.You should see what parh is necessary for redirection.With experiments.Have an eye on my paradigm of working example and figure out what its wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D ! i will work the entire night probly. i Want to figure this sh*it out ahahah

Comment: I hope yo find it!

Comment: i thought at what you wrote before, and i got an idea "What if i try to find the URL of my page, and getting it from code?" then i discorvered $location.absUrl(); and it doesn't works too. im really tired of this. What the hell is wrong ??? ahahahha